# Is it possible to compute the Fourier transform with Integrate in all cases where FourierTransform succeeds?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, fourier-analysis

I am trying to write a function that generalizes the Laplace and Fourier transforms, but I'm having trouble getting `Integrate` to play along. The function is called `FLTransform` in the following snippet, where `FTransform` and `LTransform` are the equivalent Fourier and Laplace transforms, respectively:

```
FTransform[expr_, t_, \[Omega]_] := FourierTransform[expr, t, \[Omega], FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];
LTransform[expr_, t_, s_] := BilateralLaplaceTransform[expr, t, s];
FLTransform[expr_, t_, s_] := Integrate[expr Exp[-s t], {t, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}];
```

First, I tried `Cos[t]`. The Fourier transform is defined for this function, but the Laplace transform is not (well, it is only defined for `Re[s] == 0`):

```
f[t] := Cos[t];
FTransform[f[t], t, \[Omega]]
LTransform[f[t], t, s]
FLTransform[f[t], t, s]
```

`FTransform` and `LTransform` yield the following outputs:

```
\[Pi] DiracDelta[-1 + \[Omega]] + \[Pi] DiracDelta[1 + \[Omega]]
BilateralLaplaceTransform[Cos[t], t, s]
```

However, `FLTransform` fails with the message `Integrate::idiv`, as the integral does not technically converge (thus the `DiracDelta`). Is it possible to rectify this somehow?

Comment: `FTransform` and `LTransform` are **not** equivalent  ?

Comment: The short answer to the question in your title is *no*. See [What integrals can `FourierTransform` evaluate that `Integrate` cannot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/262548/27951) and the discussion therein, which I think may be a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk When `Re[s] == 0`, they are mathematically equivalent in that $s = i \omega$. Perhaps I should have stated this with something like `FTransform[expr_, t_, s_] := FourierTransform[expr, t, s/I, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];` - frankly, I wasn't sure if this is allowed.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks for the link! I'm considering rephrasing my question to "Is it possible to get `BilateralLaplaceTransform` to automatically evaluate for `Re[s] == 0` as necessary?", as that would also be sufficient to define my `FLTransform`.

Comment: Sometimes `GenerateConditions->False` can help. But only sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the realy answer, just the beginning...

```
ClearAll["`*"]; Remove["`*"]

FTransform[expr_, t_, s_] := FourierTransform[expr, t, s, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}];
LTransform[expr_, t_, s_] := (BilateralLaplaceTransform[expr, t, s] /. s -> I*s);
LDTransform[expr_, t_, s_] := (LaplaceTransform[expr /. t -> -t, t, s] /. 
 s -> I*s) + (LaplaceTransform[expr /. t -> t, t, s] /. s -> -I*s);
FLTransform[expr_, t_, s_] := Integrate[expr*Exp[I s t], {t, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}];
MTransform[expr_, t_, s_] := (MellinTransform[expr /. t -> Log[t], t, s] /. s -> I*s);

f[t] := 1/(1 + t^2);(* For: Cos[t] some methods don't work*)

FTransform[f[t], t, s]
LTransform[f[t], t, s]
LDTransform[f[t], t, s]
FLTransform[f[t], t, s]
MTransform[f[t], t, s]
```

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I should clarify - I would like to define `FLTransform` in terms of `Integral` such that it *does* work for the input `Cos[t]`.

Comment: @QuaternionsRock it is better to clarify this also in the OP by editing the question and adding this clarification to the question itself. Comments can be easily overlooked.